# c# opennetcf RegistryHelper.SaveHiveBasedKey

Tags: c#, c, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

I am trying to figure out the best approach to backup the entire registry off of a windows mobile 6.1 device. I found the OPENNETCF RegistryHelper class that supposedly will save a hive based key?

Could someone help me figure out first if this is best approach?

Below is the code I am trying to use and keep getting error "Unable to generate registry file"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\StorageManager\Profiles\SDMMC");
            string outputkey = @"\Storage Card\key.reg";

            SaveHiveBasedKey(Key, outputkey);
        }


        public static void SaveHiveBasedKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey keyToSave, string destinationPath)
        {
            RegistryHelper.SaveHiveBasedKey(keyToSave, destinationPath);
        }
```

Exception details:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  Message="Unable to generate registry file"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=80
  StackTrace:
    at OpenNETCF.Win32.RegistryHelper.SaveHiveBasedKey()
    at mc9090clone.Form1.SaveHiveBasedKey()
    at mc9090clone.Form1.button1_Click()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
    at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
    at mc9090clone.Program.Main()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Windows Mobile uses Ram based registry.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           string outputkey = @"\key.dat";

            //save registry to dat file
           SaveRamBasedRegistry(outputkey);
            //Restore registry file
           RestoreRamBasedRegistry(outputkey);
        }



        public static void SaveRamBasedRegistry(string destinationPath)
        {
            RegistryHelper.SaveRamBasedRegistry(destinationPath);
        }

        public static void RestoreRamBasedRegistry(string destinationPath)
        {
            RegistryHelper.RestoreRamBasedRegistry(destinationPath);
        }
```